# React Native setInterval doubles it self after restarting app

Tags: react-native, setinterval

All the time setInterval acts as I am expecting except for one instance. If user leaves the app by clicking 'home button' and restarts app by clicking the icon (not by selecting from overview), the old setInterval haven't stopped. It starts over again, and there are now running 2 setIntervals. It goes on and on if I repeat this process and user can end up running hundreds of intervals at the same time.

How do I prevent this? I want to run only one instance of seInterval at the time.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {
    AsyncStorage,
    Text,
    View,
    AppState,
} from 'react-native';


import timer from'react-native-timer';

class Code_temp extends Component {

    redirect(routeName){
        this.props.navigator.push({
            name: routeName
        });
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            appState:           AppState.currentState,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);

        this.setState({showMsg: true}, () => timer.setInterval(
            this, 'hideMsg', () =>{
                console.log( 1 );
            }, 1000
        ));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {

        AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    }

    _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {

        }
        this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
    };

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Test
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Code_temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not clearing the setInterval when the component is unmounted, also remove 'this' from setinterval arguments

```
  componentDidMount() {
        timer.clearInterval('hideMsg');
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    this.setState({showMsg: true}, () => timer.setInterval(
        'hideMsg', () =>{
            console.log( 1 );
        }, 1000
    ));
}

componentWillUnmount() {

  timer.clearInterval('hideMsg');

};
```

Comment: add clearinterval to componentDidMount too, above rest of the code in componentDidMount

Comment: Why are you passing 'this' as first argument in setInterval ? First arguement should be name of the timer

Comment: Yeees :) :) 'this' was the problem. Rookie mistake. Thank You!